# How to incrementally insert log file into mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have been searching the web to see if there is a simple way to do incremental data load into a MySQL database (community edition) - without writing a specialized process.

This could be applicable to any log data - for example Apache log or some other log file. In my case I have a logfile that is constantly appended to, and once it reaches 20 MB, it is gzipped and renamed, and new file gets created with original name. I want to insert the data to a data table as it gets added to the file - ideally in real time, but at least be able to run on demand or every 30 seconds.

Is there some inbuilt feature that allows incremental load of a file?

Thanks

Comment: MySQL supports LOAD_FILE might be usefull https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file in combination with MySQL events.. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` and chunked CSVs is low-tech but highly effective.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will find a way with MySQL to do this without a specialized process. The answer could rely on your O/S,. I would recommend putting another tag on your question. For example, if you are using Linux, you might search for "linux syslog mysql" for an answer. Just read any warnings about using a database for system logging.